# Displaying the Sum of Values from All of Its Dependent Models in Foreignkey Dropdown

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following two models:

```
class Model_ItemName(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Item name: {}, current quantity: {}".format(self.item_name, ...) # How to include the **sum** of all of its "quantity" from "Model_Transaction" here


class Model_Transaction(models.Model):
    item_name = models.ForeignKey(Model_ItemName)
    quantity = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

When selecting the foreign-key dropdown from the Model_Transaction model inside CreateView, how can we not only display the "item_name", but also show the sum of all of its related "quantity"? So for example in the dropdown, the selection would look like this:

```
Item name: ABC, current quantity: 213 # (200 + 15 - 2)
...
Item name: XYZ, current quantity: 91 # (87 + 4)
```

In this way, the user will know what is total quantity of that selected item, before adding/subtracting that item.

I welcome any kind of suggestion/solution. Thank you

Comment: you can do in view using annotate instead of writing in models

Comment: How can we do that inside Createview? Sorry I modified the description to be more specific.

Comment: what is (200 + 15 - 2)?

Comment: Those are values that have been saved in the database. For example, initially "ABC" had 200 units, then we added 15 units in one day, and subtracted 2 units on the day after. So the remaining quantity for item "ABC" is 213.

Comment: from django.db.models import Sum
Model_Transaction.objects.values('item_name')
             .annotate(utotal_quty=Sum('quantity'))  can you try this? in django shell if it simple to you